# Is Steiner Triple System Always Regular?

Tags: combinatorics, hypergraphs

I know that there exists $S(2,3,n)$, when $n\equiv 1,3\mod 6$. $S(2,3,7)$ is the Fano plane and $S(2,3,9)$ is an affine plane. These two examples are in fact both regular hypergraphs, i.e. every vertices has the same degree. Are Steiner Triple Systems always regular?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Steiner Triple System is always regular.  Consider a STS on $n$ vertices and choose any vertex $v$.  We know $v$ shares exactly one edge with every other vertex, and each edge containing $v$ contains exactly 2 other vertices.  For this reason, the degree of $v$ is $\frac{n-1}{2}$.  All vertices will have this same degree, so the STS is regular.

Comment: To be clear, a given vertex shares an edge with any other vertex due to the fact that each block in the STS is defined by precisely two vertices. So it would appear that we're viewing every STS as a complete graph on $n$ vertices, and the $K_3$ subgraphs which correspond to blocks define our edge set?